# Adding days to date in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a column with dates(reg_dates) and another columns with number of days(num_days) for each id. I want to add number of days(num_days) to columns of dates(reg_dates) to create a new column (new_date) for each id.

So far, I have tried:

1. select *, sum(date(reg_dates) + interval(num_days)) over(partition by id) as new_date from data;
2. select *, sum(reg_dates) over(partition by id) as new_date from data;
   no luck so far.

ADD_MONTHS works but add_days seems to be non-existent in netezza.

I also plan to try converting days to month and using the ADD_MONTHS but wanted to see if there is a more straightforward way to do this in netezza.

Comment: Sample data and desired reulsts would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select d.*, reg_date + num_days * interval '1 day' as new_date
from data;
```

I'm not sure why you are using window functions based on the description.

Comment: I'm using window function because I have multiple rows of observations for each id. e.g: A school allows a student to borrow a book for 30, 90, 15 days based on demand from multiple students and availability of number of copies of the same book. A student has option to bring the book back to the library and get it for another 30, 45, 90 days. Therefore, the goal is to calculate new return date for each book based on the number of days it was loaned for. I added over clause to your suggested code but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I think you are right, I was approaching this problem in a wrong way. What I should do is to break my entire approach in two pieces, calculate new date and then aggregate in next step. Thank you Gordon! :)